# Can Thread survive App termination?

Tags: .net, multithreading

If a .NET program creates and starts a `System.Threading.ThreadPool` thread, and then the program ends (either naturally or by crashing):

- Is it possible for the `Thread` to survive and carry on processing on its own?
- Is it possible that an App will look like it has terminated due to the main UI thread having ended, but for a background thread to carry on running invisibly?

Comment: Second bullet is possible for a thread that doesn't have IsBackground = true.  Which will not be a threadpool thread.  Or the app looks terminated because the user interface is gone but the UI thread is still running, a classic side-effect of using DoEvents().

Answer (score 3):

No. By definition, if one of the threads of the process is still working, then it *has not actually ended*.

Comment: Is it generic rule or system dependent ? Sometimes you can hear about zombie processes or zombie threads for example under Unix. Is it just naming issue ?

Comment: It is what "the process has ended" _means_. "Zombie processes" under Unix is a fancy name for process IDs that _don't identify any process_ anymore but cannot yet be reused because the parent process of the former process has not yet been informed that it has terminated, and might still use the ID to retrieve its exit status. (In some threading implementations, threads are implemented as lightweight processes, and can therefore also give rise to zombie entries in the process table).

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko: Hmm, perhaps you're confusing "daemon" with "zombie"? Daemons work by forking a child process to do the actual work and then having the main process exit immediately. The shell that started the main process will notice that it has terminated, while the child process keeps running on its own.

Comment: Thanks, I was just asking out of curiosity and that's pretty good explanation for me. Regards + 1.

Answer (score 1):

a thread can't live independently of a process, so no.

Answer (score 0):

No. And from [the horse's mouth (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)

> The threads in the managed thread pool are background threads. That
>   is, their `IsBackground` properties are true. This means that a
>   `ThreadPool` thread will not keep an application running after all
>   foreground threads have exited.